# How to replace a particular column in a CSV with some string?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, awk

Sorry for a really basic question. How to replace a particular column in a **tab separated** file with some string, say "xyz"?

e.g.

**Input:**

```
abc\t  def\t   \t   xyz
pqr\t  ert\t   \t   yut
```

**Output:**

```
abc\t  def\t   new_str\t   xyz
pqr\t  ert\t   new_str\t   yut
```

In short, the 3rd column in my file is empty and I want to replace it with a string.

I tied something like this:

```
awk '{$3="new_str"}1' test1.csv > test1_op.csv
```

but looks like it does not maintain the tabs. Also note that the file has 400 columns, so writing an awk command something like this:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,...,$400}' in.csv > outfile.csv
```

I would like to avoid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's tab-delimited, you are on the right track by splitting on a tab, rather than `awk`'s default of splitting on any whitespace (any combination of spaces, tabs, and possibly other more esoteric types). Once you've done that, you can assign directly to the column you want to change and just print $0 again.

```
awk -F$'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {$3="new_str"; print}' in.csv > outfile.csv
```

`awk` can also process variable assignments that appear in its input file list, so this is a little cleaner-looking:

```
awk '{$3="new_str"; print}' FS=$'\t' OFS=$'\t' in.csv > outfile.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GUN sed):

```
sed -i 's/\t/new_str&/3' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly how you want to deal with whitespace, but perhaps you just want:

```
awk '{$3="new_str"}1' FS=\\t OFS=\\t
```

Note that this discards the whitespace that was originally in `$3`.  You could keep it with either:

```
awk '{$3=$3"new_str"}1' FS=\\t OFS=\\t
```

or

```
awk '{$3="   new_str"}1' FS=\\t OFS=\\t
```

depending on your needs.